# Deploying django under a sub-URL with Nginx/Fastcgi

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, django

I can't for the life of me figure out how to deploy a django site under a non-root location with Nginx/fastcgi, e.g. localhost:8080/myproject/ instead of localhost:8080/; all the examples I have seen either assume Apache or mounting at the root of the site. Here's the relevant part of my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myproject/ {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;

        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
}
```

And a minimal `urls.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello world!')),
```

)

Trying to access localhost:8080/myproject/hello gives a 404. I've tried unsuccessfully all combinations of:

- Commenting/uncommenting `fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;`
- Commenting/uncommenting `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;`
- Setting `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/myproject/'` in settings.py.

Answer (score 2):

Just pushed through the same issue myself- it turns out that the link you provided to the [Django change doc](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined) was the key to solving the problem.

Django > 1.0 uses `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` to route URLs, as the doc explained. So I took that and ran with it. For a project called 'myproject', which you'd like rooted at mydomain.com/myproject/, try this.

```
location ~ /myproject/(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO /$1;
    SCRIPT_NAME /myproject;
}
```

The rest of the fastcgi params I have in another site-wide config file. So your example would look something like

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location /myproject/ {
        # host and port to fastcgi server
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3030;

        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /myproject;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          /$1;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
}
```

with the same urls.py. The only issues I've had so far have been minor troubles keeping DRY, eg where settings.py requires absolute URLs and Django doesn't think to prepend the `SCRIPT_NAME` on the URL (think `settings.LOGIN_URL`, `settings.MEDIA_URL`).

This might be obvious, but also make sure you have another location that points to your static and admin media.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into related problem with Nginx and Gunicorn instead of fastcgi.

I wrote about my findings here:

http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2011/Sep/15/hosting-django-under-different-locations

The upshot is you can use proxy_set_header to set the SCRIPT_NAME header directly into the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies in your django setup rather than the nginx and fastcgi setup. 
You have the urls's defined as http://hostname.domain.tld/hello and not http://hostname.domain.tld/myproject/hello

So as far as django is concerned the request does not match any url is has mapped.

Please try the following in your urls.py : 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^myproject/hello$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Hello world!')),

HTH

MartinP

Comment: Yeah this works but urlconfs are supposed to be easily relocatable, i.e. moving your app under a different root should not require changing all your urls. Instead I should somehow tell Nginx to pass `/myproject/` as `SCRIPT_NAME` to Django: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined

Answer (score 0):

For Django 1.6< according to other threads on ServerFault, you should not set the SCRIPT_NAME variable, this one should be '', and you should set only PATH_INFO with $fastcgi_script_name variable.

For Django 1.6> according to the changes... this settings are no longer necessary, https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined.I have commented out both the Path info and Script Name lines in fastcgi_params (in Debian-like cases) or in the nginx.conf (RHEL cases)